# Run apache airflow scheduler within Systemd

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, airflow, virtualenvwrapper

I am using ubuntu 16.04 and virtualenvwrapper for the virtual environment. For production, I want to run automatically Airflow scheduler with Systemd.

How can I configure Airflow scheduler in a virtual environment and within Systemd?

Answer (score 4):

There are example systemd configuration files for each airflow component in https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/tree/1.9.0/scripts/systemd. Then just make sure virtualenv path for airflow, for example, `ExecStart=/my/project/venv/bin/airflow scheduler`. If your airflow home directory is different from the default (~/airflow), you can override that with `Environment="AIRFLOW_HOME=/my/airflow`.